# calling one php function from other?

Tags: php

hello i want to know how to call a function defined in one php file from some other function defined in some other php page.

Comment: Has been answered numerous times: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=calling+one+php+function+from+other and http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=include+files+php - In addition, please accept some of the answers to the 15 questions you asked so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

do like this, 
in the file where you need to call the function

```
require_once("file_having_function_that_you_need_to_call.php");

function_name($arguments); // this function is defined in 'file_having_function_that_you_need_to_call.php' file
```

Answer (score 3):

First you need to include that file either using

```
require_once or require
```

or

```
include_once or  include
```

if the function is not in class, you will call directly.

```
require("file.php");
echo getUserName("1")
```

otherwise you have to first create object and than call method

```
require("file.php");
$obj = new User();
echo $obj->getUserName("1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`include()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), [`require()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php), etc. on the other PHP file, then just put the function name followed by its arguments in parentheses.