# How would I call a function in another file?

Tags: php

For example, I have a file error-status.php, which includes a function:

```
function validateHostName($hostName)
{
    if ((strpbrk($hostName,'`~!@#$^&*()=+.[ ]{}\\|;:\'",<>/?')==FALSE) && !ctype_digit($hostName) && eregi("^([a-z0-9-]+)$",$hostName) && ereg("^[^-]",$hostName) && ereg("[^-]$",$hostName))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

...

How do I call that function from a different PHP file after invoking `require_once`?

```
require_once('error-status.php');
```

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/2295638/560299

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Include the file before you call the function.

```
include 'error-status.php';
validateHostName('myhostname');
```

Comment: The OP has already used `require_once()`. Are you suggesting that he include the file again?

Comment: @ignacio, no simply was just an example. He could of course just use require_once.

Comment: You should *definitely* use `require_once` in this case because a) `error-status.php` is absolutely vital to correct execution of the very next line of code b) `error-status.php` must *definitely* only be 'loaded' once since subsequent loading would cause a 'function already defined' error.

Answer (score 4):

I would simply extend the class or use the require `/include`, then:

```
$var = new otherClass;
$getString = $var->getString();
```

Answer (score 2):

include or require the file before you call the function.

Answer (score 1):

Building on what [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799267/how-to-call-function-in-other-file-php/5799279#5799279) said, if your function is inside a class in error-status.php,  you'll need to initialise the class and call the function through that.

http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.class.php

Comment: This link is broken.

Answer (score 1):

See an example below,

first_file.php :

```
<?php
    function calling_function(){ 
       $string = "Something";
       return $string; 
    }
?>
```

In your Second file

second_file.php :

```
<?php
     include 'first_file.php';
     $return_value = calling_function();
     echo $return_value;
?>
```