# PHP get variables in class from another file

Tags: php, oop, class

For example I have file `config.php:`

```
$host = 'localhost';
$db = 'logger';
$user = 'user';
$pwd = 'pass';
```

and file `mysqlClass.php`

```
class mysql{

public function connect(){

//hot get get variables form confing.php there ?
}

}
```

And I not know hot to get variables from confin.php in mysql class, I can't change config.php file

Comment: Pass the variables through a function, or call them globally. Google that information.

Comment: pass them to the constructor of the class.

Comment: Do not use the `mysql_` database functions; use something like PDO instead. http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Possible repeat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5799267/how-to-call-function-in-other-file-php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `require_once()` the file

```
public function connect() {
  require_once 'config.php';
  // ...code...
}
```

Comment: Also a possible way, but including files in functions (apart from autoloader), is this good style?

Answer (score 3):

Use function parameters:

```
class mysql{
    public function connect($host, $db, $user, $pass){
        // do something with the variables
    }
}
```

When instantiating `mysql` now, use:

```
require 'config.php';
$mysql = new mysql($host, $db, $user, $pass);
```

Comment: This is a better solution, in line with what object-oriented code should be. Don't use the require_once thing within your Mysql class.

Comment: That's exactly what I commented to @bsdnoobz

Answer (score 2):

```
include 'config.php';
include_once 'config.php';
```

or

```
require 'config.php';
require_once 'config.php';
```

Inside of `mysqlClass.php`

The difference between `include` and `require` is that `require` will also produce a fatal `E_COMPILE_ERROR` level error, stopping the script, whereas, `include` only produces `E_WARNING`, which will NOT stop the script. The difference between `include_once` or `require_once` and `include` or `require` is that PHP will check to see if the file has been included already, and if it hasn't, it will include it. If it has, it will **not** load it again.